# Pause interpolation of template string in FTL

Tags: macros, freemarker

I want to pass a dynamic string to FTL Macro. But I don't want the template string to be interpolated when I am calling the macro from FTL. I want the template string to be interpolated inside Macro only. So that I can make the Macro reusable by sending dynamic Template strings as parameter. As I am new to Apache FTL so I don't have much idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what do you want to achieve, but I guess something like this:

```
<#macro m s>
  <#local parsedS = s?interpret>
  <#list ['John Doe', 'Jane Doe'] as name>
    <p><@parsedS />
  </#list>
</#macro>

<@m r"Hello ${name}!" />
```

which will print:

```
<p>Hello John Doe!
<p>Hello Jane Doe!
```

Some notes:

- I haven't just used the parameter as a string with an interpolation,
  but as an template fragment (so that auto-escaping, if you use it,
  will be applied, also you could use `#if` and such in the value of
  `s`).
- As the template fragment is evaluated for multiple types in my
  example, I have assigned the result of `?interpret` to a local
  variable, otherwise you could just write `<@s?interpret />`.
- As of
  the `r` before the string literal, that tells FreeMarker that `${}`
  (and `\` escapes) must not be interpreted.